# Trouble with the sentence 「お手並み拝見てところかな」

Tags: meaning, particles

The sentence in the title supposedly means something like

> 「あなたの技術を見せてもらうかな」

I roughly understand what this sentence means as a whole but i'm having trouble parsing it.

I know that お手並み拝見 means: let's see what you've got; show me what you've got... accroding to [jisho dictionary](http://jisho.org/) but i can hardly understand how it's used, example sentences show that it's ususually followed by the particle と so i'm guessing this て is another form of と ?

I also do not seem to understand what the ところ is doing here.

Comment: って is short for という. Taken together with ところ, the sentence means something like 'I guess it's time for you to show me what you've got', 'I guess I should say, "Show me what you've got."'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible translation could be:

> "Perhaps it's time to see what you've got."

「お手並み拝見・てところ・かな」

- **かな** - shows doubt or suggestion, "**Perhaps**..."
- **てところ**　⇒　というところ - the time or circumstance to do something, "...**it's time**..."
- **お手並み拝見** - to see what someone is able to do (sarcastically polite to indicate doubtfulness), "...**to see what (you've) got**"